# Behaviour of update listener in TurnBasedMatch

Tags: android, google-play-games

As in the playgameservies examples - SkeletonActivity.java - I'm doing registerMatchUpdateListener in the onConnected method and implementing OnTurnBasedMatchUpdateReceivedListener. This works fine. A player can take a turn and the other player's listener receives the update. And if the activity is in the backgroud the updates appear as notifications in the notification bar. This is all as I'd expect.

However, if a player taps a notification to bring the activity into the foreground, subsequent updates always generate another notification. I would expect that the listener should have been re-registered and the activity should start handling the updates again.

Updated : Calling both unregisterMatchUpdateListener and registerMatchUpdateListener in onResume also doesn't allow the activity to start handling the updates.

Am I right to expect that? And, if so, any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: This sounds like a bug, as the documentation for registerMatchUpdateLister states: 

"If a listener is registered by this method, the incoming match update will not generate a status bar notification as long as this client remains connected."

Might want to log something with the Android team and see what they say. 

Also, does this issue *only* occur if the user opens the app through the notification? If they manually open it by clicking the app icon, do they *not* receive notifications?

Comment: Yes, ignoring the notification and opening the app manually works the same way : they no longer receive notifications and the listener handles the updates. Doing that test revealed a bug in my game! So thanks for the reply and thanks for helping find a bug I'd missed.